# Lazy initialization exception in TestNG unit testcase to test Spring service layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, service, testng

I am getting the lazy initialization exception while testing the spring service layer with TestNG testcases. Could you please help me out to resolve the issue. Not sure if I'm missing any thing in the below testcase. But if I create and execute the testcase for same method in Dao layer then its working fine.

Comment: Let's see your `InspectionQuestion` class to start.

Comment: I have added the InspectionQuestion class and hbm for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the below annotation in the test class, I'm able to maintain the session. @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="hibernateTransactionManager", defaultRollback=true).

Answer (score 0):

You have the following mapping

```
<set name="validResponses" lazy="true" inverse="true"
```

which lazily loads the `InspectionQuestion.validResponses` field.

I'm going to assume that

```
InspectionQuestion iq = inspectionStepQuestionService.getActiveInspectionQuestionByCode(QuestionType.COUNTRY_ORIGIN);
```

is done within a `Session` and a `Transaction`. When the method returns, the `Transaction` is committed and the `Session` is closed. As such, any fields that are not eagerly loaded are in an un-initialized stated. Trying to initialize them after this will cause the `LazyInitializationException` that you are seeing.

The simple solution would be to change `lazy="true"` to `lazy="false"`, but this may not be what you want always.

Instead, maybe change your `InspectionStepQuestionService` methods to fully initialize your entities when required

```
Hibernate.initialize(inspectionQuestion /* or entity to return */);
```

Comment: Actuly I'm not supposed to update both hbm as well as InspectionStepQuestionService. All I need to do is to update the InspectionStepQuestionServiceImplTest class.  Is it possible to avoid the exception by updating my testNG class i.e. InspectionStepQuestionServiceImplTest class

Comment: Thanks Sotirios Delimanolis. 
I've got the another resolution of this problem.By adding the below annotation in the test class, I'm able to maintain the session.
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="hibernateTransactionManager", defaultRollback=true).